# A odd question php OOP

Tags: php, oop

Hey guys.  I was designing a model for some data, and wanted it to work like: `$this->groupmodel->VARIABLE->FUNCTION(VAR1, VAR2);` to call a function, where VARIABLE is changeable to anything, and passed to the function.

This feels more correct (then say `$this->groupmodel->FUNCTION(VARIABLE, VAR1, VAR2)`), because each `VARIABLE` has the exact same functions, and the functions are being preformed (technically) on `VARIABLE`.  Is this possible?
Note that `VARIABLE` can be set anywhere (in its own function or in the function being called) (it is persistent throughout the class, but needs to be set each call).

Max

Comment: It is not an *OOP*, it is an attempt to do terrible things using objects. *OOP* **is** a paradigm invented to lower complexity of programs, make programs more clear, understandable and readable. But you want something that will prevent of following all those ideas.

Comment: In fact, the example that mazzzzz posted resembles somehow the approach some languages have to implementing OOP.  The object being called is automatically referred to as $this, and that's pretty much all.

Comment: I love how someone who has no idea how my program functions will jump to such high conclusions about how it *should* be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a class implementing the functions you want to use, and all your "variables" should be objects of that class.  For instance:

```
class Kid {
    private $age = 0;
    public function _construct($age){
      $this->age = $age;
    }
    public function birthday() { // implement in Kid instead of in Groupmodel
      $this->age++;
      echo "Growing old... ";
    }
    public function age($age_new = null){  // age setter and getter
      if(!is_null($age_new)){
        $this->age = $age_new;
      }
      return $this->age;
    }
}
```

And then inside your groupmodel:

```
class GroupModel {

  private $variables;

  public function _set($name, $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->variables)) {
      $this->variables[$name]->age($value);
    } else {
      $this->variables[$name] = new Kid($value);
    }
  }

  public function _get($name) {
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->variables)) {
      return $this->variables[$name];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

so you can call:

```
$this->groupmodel = new GroupModel()
$this->groupmodel->var1 = 8
$this->groupmodel->var1->birthday();  // will add 1 to var1's age and print "Growing old"
$this->groupmodel->var1 = 9  // will replace var1's age
```

What we are doing here is creating objects of class Kid automatically every time you try to set a property of the GroupModel object.  (This is what the magic method _set() does)

In fact it creates them as elements of a private array instead of real properties of GroupModel.

Then, when trying to access those "properties", _get() will be invoked and it will retrieve the element of the array and return it.

As it will be an object of class Kid, you could call every method it implements (like birthday()).

For more information on Overloading and magic methods like _get and _set, see:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members

Comment: Could you be a bit more descriptive in you example?  If I wasn't to clear, each function after `variable` is the exact same for each `variable`.  I don't see how I can adapt your solution to do that.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.3 let you use very nice thing called [late static bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Lets say you have 2 classes: Foo which extends groupmodel:

```
class groupmodel { 
      const MY_CONST = 'groupmodel'; 

      protected function myName(){
         echo static::MY_CONST; //Will print 'groupmodel'; 
      }


      protected function whoAmI(){ 
        //do something here
      }
}
```

and Foo:

```
class Foo extends groupmodel { 
      const MY_CONST = 'ClassFoo'; 

      public function tellMyName(){ 
        $this->myName(); //Will print 'ClassFoo';
      }
}
```

Actually, the idea is instead of using

```
$this->groupmodel->FUNCTION(VARIABLE, VAR1, VAR2)
OR 
$this->groupmodel->VARIABLE->FUNCTION(VAR1, VAR2);
```

you will use:

```
$object = new Foo(); 
$object->tellMyName(); //Will print 'ClassFoo'
```

and now $object will grant all of *groupmodel* methods.

another important thing with your case and for working with OOP as much as you can is setting up an [abstract class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)

Comment: You talk of late static binding, but you don't use it.  None of the functions are static.  This will work without late static binding (except for the static keyword).

Comment: I agree that you may use it while using static methods, but you can use it on your instance. so if you will use self::MY_CONST it won't work (see my example). 

You will be able to do some more sophisticated things, and create a fully dynamic inheriting by using late static bindings with both of method types (static and instance).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  php allows you to use variables for both member and function access.  For example: `$this->groupmodel->$myvar->myfunc($var1, $var2);`

This will call `$this->groupmodel->{Whatever-string-is-stored-in-myvar}`.

Note that if you want to do this, groupmodel must be set in the class and $myvar must be a public member in the `groupmodel` and the contents of $myvar must be a valid member that is also a class that implements `myfunc()`.  This is a lot of coupled dependency (hence zerkms' disparaging of this approach).  Would help to know what you're trying to do, though.

Comment: groupmodel manages a group of people.  The groupmodel class is stateless (nothing rolls over from one function call to the other), so I need to set which member of the group (retrieved from the db) I am running the function on (and sense it's a model, and saved directly to the database, I reasoned it should just be stateless).  I wanted an intuitive interface for each member (instead of including their name in the function call, and that is how I came up with this.